# cucumber floating point numbers

Tags: int, cucumber, double

When I generate a a cucumber phrase as such

Then I should have result 180.123

The code generated in IntelliJ at least is

```
@Then("^I should have result (\\d+).(\\d+)$")
public void I_should_have_result_(int arg1, int arg2) throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Is there any way to get a single double rather than having to join two ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify your Gherkin step to

```
Then I should have result "180.23"
```

its implementation would be

```
@Then("^I should have result \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void I_should_have_result(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

which is quite easy to convert to a float.

Comment: Yes that's what I did - but pretty unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ancient question but I'll answer it anyway as I have searched everywhere myself without much luck.

You can use `(\\d+\\.\\d+)` to specify that you want a double:

In Java:

```java
@When("^I get a number (\\d+\\.\\d+)$")
public void iGetANumber(double my_number) {
    // Test code here
}
```

And in Objective-C (with Cucumberish):

```c
When(@"^I get a number (\\d+\\.\\d+)$", ^(NSArray<NSString*>* args, NSDictionary* userInfo) {
    double my_number = [args[0] doubleValue];

    // Test code here
}
```

I believe you can also use the `(\\d+\\.\\d+)` specifier but declare the variable as a float instead of a double.  At least it worked in Java when I tried.